# Implicit conversion between RWCString and const char *

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, rogue-wave

```
RWCString str = "Y";
str.append("ES");
if("YES" == str)
    cout << "YES == str" << endl;
if(str == "YES")
    cout << "str == YES" << endl;
```

How does the implicit conversion take place in both cases? Which one is safe to use? 
RWCString is a string class which has a constructor taking const char* and an conversion operator to const char*

Comment: I think that a temporary of type `RWCString` is constructed from the `const char*` string. This is more likely to happen because of this: `RWCString str = "Y";`.

Comment: Why are you using a third-party string library instead of `std::string`, exactly?

Comment: Im working on existing code which uses this library. I came across this line and wondering if this will work always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is extremely likely that `==` is overloaded for comparisons between `const char*` and `RWCString`.

Otherwise either `str` is converted to `const char *` or the calls are ambiguous:

`str == "YES"` is ambiguous if there is an external or member `operator==` comparing two `RWCString`s.

`"YES" == str` is ambiguous if there is an external `operator==` comparing two `RWCString`s.

(assuming that the arguments to the `operator==` are passed normally -- either through a copy, or a `const` reference).

Comment: @ashot: the question states that there is a conversion to `const char*` (last sentence of question), so i guess, the answer is yes.

Comment: @liijie are you sure,that RWCString can implicitly convert to const char * ? Becouse If it can't and const char * can implicitly convert to RWCSTRing, than I can't see any ambiguous?